# iOS deep linking with Amazon Music app

Tags: ios, deep-linking, mobile-application

This is a fairly straightforward one: to date, can an iOS app deep link or in any way launch Amazon Music to play a specific song/load an artist or album? How much of this can be done?

If you're feeling really generous, could you describe how to find the URLs to deep link to third party apps like AM, Facebook, Twitter and Spotify?

Answer (score 2):

So I opened up the "Amazon Music" .ipa file (it's basically just a `.zip` file you can unzip) and in the app's `Info.plist` file I see a URL scheme that the app answers to:

```
   <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.amazon.mp3</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>amznmp3</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
```

Unfortunately, this is not a public scheme.  That is, there's no documentation available for it that can be googled ([or I would have expected to have found it on a page like this](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/deep-linking-to-the-amazon-client)).

This means you will probably have do additional research to figure out what kind of parameter to pass along with the scheme.  For example, [on this page](http://net-s.sakura.ne.jp/URLSchemes.html) I see a potential parameter of "`fb164734381262`".  Perhaps it's a mp3 file identifier?

Answer (score 1):

My application is a little different, but may be helpful.  I am using the Workflow app to automate several things. I can interact with the Amazon Music app through the URL below.
https://music.amazon.com/playlists/B0797C4SN9?do=play
When the URL is opened in Workflow, it causes the Amazon Music app to open. A specific playlist is opened, then it starts playing.
You can create others by opening the app, sharing the playlist to notes. Deleting all of the information after the ? from the URL. Then add do=play to the end of the URL. 
I think this would apply to songs and albums as well.
I would really like to know how to get the shuffle playlist from URL, so if somebody figures that out, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Kyle365 works with iOS Shortcuts as well, was able to play a private and public playlist by copying the playlist’s url (share > copy) and changed the url to include ?do=play at the end. I created a shortcut that opens this url and Shortcuts recognizes the url as an Amazon Music url and opens it directly in the Amazon Music app and starts playing it. 
Example of Url: 
https://music.amazon.com/user-playlists/somePlaylistId?do=play